# Set JTextArea frame size with Integer

Tags: integer, jpanel, size, frame, jtextarea

Is it possible to set the size of a JTextArea with Integer?
Because when i use

```
static JTextArea textfeld = new JTextArea(33, 90);
```

it wont make a Textarea with Int but some other size.
So is there any way to set the size of it with integer?

Sorry for my bad grammar D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use textfeld.setBounds(int allignmentX, int allignmentY, int height, int width); to set the bounds of the JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

The JTextArea class constructor according to java doc is the following:

```
JTextArea(int rows, int columns)
```

Constructs a new empty TextArea with the specified number of rows and columns.
So as you can see, the arguments 33 and 90 provide the rows and columns for the text area and not a pixel value or anything.

- If you want to manage the dimensions of JTextArea use the inherited method from Component class which is:

  public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)

Comment: Yea but how i can make it with a int value?

Comment: check the edit i made, is this what you are searching for?

Comment: Yep the width is now working bot the height still dosent work

Comment: Try writing the following: textfeld = new JTextArea(); and then do textfield.setBounds(x,y, width, height);